# Uniqueness of least common multiple up to associates

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, least-common-multiple

After being given the following definition of the least common multiple, $lcm$:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $x,y\in R$. It is said that $m \in R$ is the **least common multiplier** of $x$ and $y$ if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> - $x | m$ and $y | m$
> - If $x|m^{\prime}$ and $y|m^{\prime}$, then $m|m^{\prime}$

As is the case for the **greatest common divisor** in such a ring, I want to say that the **$lcm$ is unique up to associates**, meaning if $m$ and $m^{\prime}$ are both $lcm(x,y)$, then $m | m^{\prime}$ and $m^{\prime}|m$, and we write $m \sim m^{\prime}$.

To justify this, I give the following argument:

> Suppose first that $m = lcm(x,y)$. Then this implies that $x|m$, $y|m$. If $m^{\prime}$ is any other multiple of $x$ and $y$ (including another alleged $lcm$), we also have that $x|m^{\prime}$, $y|m^{\prime}$. So, we must have that $m|m^{\prime}$.
>
> Suppose instead that $m^{\prime} = lcm(x,y)$. Then this implies that $x|m^{\prime}$, $y|m^{\prime}$. If $m$ is any other multiple of $x$ and $y$ (including another alleged $lcm$), we also have that $x|m$, $y|m$. So, we must have that $m^{\prime}|m$.
>
> Since both $m$ and $m^{\prime}$ are the $lcm(x,y)$, we must have that $m|m^{\prime}$ and $m^{\prime}|m$. Therefore, $m$ and $m^{\prime}$ are associates - i.e., $m \sim m^{\prime}$.

My question is whether my proof is correct and looks how it's generally supposed to look.

If not, how should I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall plan is good, but I think the *phrasing* of

> Suppose first that $m = lcm(x,y)$. ...
>
> Suppose instead that $m^{\prime} = lcm(x,y)$. ....

is off. In both of these paragraph, you're actually assuming that both $m$ and $m'$ satisfy your definition, so you should make these two assumptions once and for all at the beginning of the proof.

And the notation $m = \mathit{lcm}(x,y)$ is not really fortunate when the concept is not *the* least common multiple, but *a* least common multiple. (Even in good old $\mathbb Z$ there will generally be *two* least common multiples, namely a positive one and its opposite).

So the beginning should be written something like

> Suppose that $m$ and $m'$ are both least common multiples of $x$ and $y$.
>
> Then, by definition, we have $x\mid m$, $y\mid m$, $x\mid m'$, $y\mid m'$.
>
> Since $x\mid m'$ and $y\mid m'$ we have (again by definition) $m\mid m'$. . . .

Comment: thank you! Would it be possible for you to help me with this one as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249021/existence-of-the-least-common-multiple-in-a-unique-factorization-domain It is along the same lines. Thanks again!