# Existence of the least common multiple in a Unique Factorization Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains, least-common-multiple

Let $x,y \in R$, where $R$ is a unique factorization domain.

Let $P$ be the set of all representatives in each class of associate irreducible elements of $R$.

Then, suppose $x,y\in R$ are nonzero, nonunit elements (**First Question**: How would this proof change if either $x$ or $y$ is zero or is a unit of $R$?)

Then, since $R$ is a unique factorization domain, we can express $x$ and $y$ as the (unique) products (up to permutation of factors)
$$ \displaystyle  x = p_{1}^{t_{11}}p_{2}^{t_{12}}\cdots p_{k}^{t_{1k}}u_{1} $$

$$ \displaystyle  y = p_{1}^{t_{21}}p_{2}^{t_{22}}\cdots p_{k}^{t_{2k}}u_{2} $$

adding in, if necessary, extra factors $p_{i}^{0}$ to the factorization of either $x$ or $y$.

(Also note that here $p_{i} \in P$, $u_{i} \in U(R)$, $t_{j} \geq 0$, $p_{i} \neq p_{j}$ for $i \neq j$.)

Now, for each $j \leq k$, let $s_{j} = \max(t_{1j}, t_{2j})$, and let 
$$ \displaystyle m = p_{1}^{s_{1}}p_{2}^{s_{2}}\cdots p_{k}^{s_{k}}. $$

Now, by construction, $m$ is a multiple of both $x$ and $y$.

We must prove that it is the least common multiple of $x$ and $y$ (up to associates):

Assume $m^{\prime}$ is another multiple of $x$ and $y$.  Now, I was told to model this proof after a proof I have for the $\gcd$. For that proof, there was a $d$ constructed to be a divisor of both $x$ and $y$ by choosing $\min(t_{1j}, t_{2j})$ instead. Then, they showed that $d^{\prime}|d$, where $d^{\prime}$ was some other divisor of both $x$ and $y$. **Second Question**: Do I want to show here then that $m|m^{\prime}$? Is that sufficient for showing that the $m$ I came up with is the $lcm$?

If so, I'm going to need some help with that part. In the proof for the $\gcd$, they use the fact that since the factorizations of $x$ and $y$ are unique, $x$ and $y$ have no divisors $p \in P$ distinct from the $p_{j}$'s, and go on to say that since $d^{\prime}$ is a divisor of $x$, it has a factorization $$d^{\prime}=p_{1}^{r_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}}\cdots p_{k}^{r_{k}}v,\quad v \in U(R),\, r_{j} \geq 0$$.

From here they say that the fact that $d^{\prime}$ is a divisor of both $x$ and $y$ implies that $r_{j} \leq t_{ij}$ for $i = 1,2$, and all $j$, and hence $r_{j} \leq s_{j}$. Then, we have 
$$ d = d^{\prime}\cdot p_{1}^{s_{1}-r_{1}}p_{2}^{s_{2}}\cdots p_{k}^{s_{k}-r_{k}}v^{-1}$$
so that $d^{\prime}|d$.

**Third Question**: Can I just adapt this last part for $lcm$ instead of $\gcd$? Suppose I define

$$m^{\prime}=p_{1}^{r_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}}\cdots p_{k}^{r_{k}}v,\quad v \in U(R),\, r_{j} \geq 0 $$

**Then, I can say that $m^{\prime}$ is a multiple of both $x$ and $y$. Would this mean then that $r_{j} \geq t_{ij}$ for $i = 1,2$ and all $j$, and hence that $r_{j} \geq s_{j}$?**

**If so, then how would I express $m^{\prime}$ in terms of $m$ like they expressed $d$ in terms of $d^{\prime}$? I'm getting a little confused by all the exponents..**. Do I just add the exponents instead of subtracting?? Can I really be that simple??

Thank you!

---

Note: The other questions that have thus far been posted (by other people) relating to this topic have not asked for differences in the proof for the case when either $x$ or $y$ is zero or a unit element (I have been told these cases are trivialities, but sometimes seeing trivialities completely worked out can be beneficial to gaining a true understanding of something). So, please do not mark this as a duplicate. I really need an answer to this question, and the other questions have not been helpful to me.

Comment: `please do not mark this as a duplicate` Your other recent question [Uniqueness of least common multiple up to associates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248756/uniqueness-of-least-common-multiple-up-to-associates) *does* ask for `unique up to associates`, and the cases `when either x or y is zero or a unit element` are trivial. How is this new question *not* a duplicate?

Comment: @dxiv I wasn't even thinking about my question - I was thinking about other people's questions regarding how to show that the lcm exists in a Unique Factorization Domain. My earlier question about uniqueness up to associates wasn't assuming anything about even being in a Unique Factorization Domain, so an lcm wasn't even guaranteed to exist at all. Here, I am trying to show that one must exist because we are now in a UFD. Also, I would like these "trivial" cases explained to me.

Comment: @dxiv in case I have miscommunicated, I will edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: `an lcm wasn't even guaranteed to exist` Right, but whenever the $\operatorname{lcm}$ *does* exist, it is guaranteed to be unique up to associates. You don't need the ring to be a UFD for that.

Comment: @dxiv aaah. Okay then, I definitely need to edit. But, still not exactly a duplicate of other people's (unanswered) questions.

Comment: @dxiv done. Also, I am asking for guidance at 3 specific crossroads in the proof, which differentiates my question from the other people's more general ones.